# Why does /user/{username} not show up automatically?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My route:

```
Route::get('/user/{username}', [
    'uses' => '\MostWanted\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@getProfile',
    'as' => 'profile.index',
]);`
```

My Controller:

```
use MostWanted\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;



class ProfileController extends Controller{

    public function getProfile($username){
        $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();

        if (!$user) {
            abort(404);
        }

        return view('profile.index')
            ->with('user', $user);

    }
}
```

The username field in the database exists and is filled in. When I go into search, the users pop up but the URL always misses out on the {username}. When I manually enter the {username} e.g. `mostwanted.dev:8000/user/yes.man`, it functions normally.

EDIT: This is the view that is hooked to (userblock.blade.php)

```
<div class="media">
<a class="pull-left" href="{{ route('profile.index', ['username' => $user->username]) }}">
    <img class="media-object" alt="{{ $user->getNameOrUsername() }}" src="">
</a>
<div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">
        <a href="{{ route('profile.index', ['username' => $user->username]) }}">{{ $user->getNameOrUsername() }}</a>
    </h4>
    @if ($user->location)
        <p>{{ $user->location }}</p>
    @endif
</div>
```

Here is the User.php:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable; 
class User extends Authenticatable    
{
protected $table = 'users';

protected $fillable = [
    'username',
    'first_name',
    'last_name',        
    'email', 
    'password',
    'location',
    'gender',
    'date_of_birth',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 
    'remember_token',
];

public function getName()
{
    if ($this->first_name && $this->last_name) {
    return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";

    }

    if ($this->first_name) {
        return $this->first_name;
    }

    return null;

}

    public function getUsername()
{
    if ($this->first_name && $this->last_name) {
    return "{$this->first_name}.{$this->last_name}";

    }

    if ($this->first_name) {
        return $this->first_name;
    }

    return null;

}

public function getNameOrUsername()
{
    return $this->getName() ?: $this->username;
}

public function getUsernameOrName()
{
    return $this->getUsername() ?: $this->username;
}

public function getFirstNameOrUsername()
{
    return $this->first_name ?: $this->username;
}
}
```

EDIT**: Search results view:

```
@extends('templates.default')

@section('content')
    <h3>Your search for "{{ Request::input('query') }}"</h3>

@if (!$users->count())
    <p>No results found.</p>
@else
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12" style="padding: 50px;">
        @foreach ($users as $user)
            @include('user/partials/userblock')
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
@endif
@stop
```

SearchController:

```
use DB;
use MostWanted\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
public function getResults(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->input('query');

    if (!$query) {

        return redirect()->route('home');

    }

    $users = User::where(DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)"),
     'LIKE', "%{$query}%") 
     ->orWhere('username', 'LIKE', "%{query}%")
     ->get();


    return view('search.results')->with('users', $users);
}
```

}

EDIT***:

ProfileController:

```
use MostWanted\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
public function getProfile($username)
{

    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();

    if (!$user) {
        abort(404);
    }

    return view('profile.index')
        ->with('user', $user);

}
}
```

Comment: I think we may need to see your view html?

Comment: View where are you generating this url?

Comment: It seems no problems with your server part. You need post your request code.

Comment: You are saying that you have a search form and when you press the submit button the url doesn't change ?

Comment: You can check what HTML does `{{ route('profile.index', ['username' => $user->username]) }}` generates. To do this press Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome and look at source code.

Comment: @ClaudioKing Sort of. After I perform the search, userblock shows up but this is the link that shows: `http://mostwanted.dev:8000/user`. I am wondering where the username part went.

@AlexeyMezenin This is the link that shows: `http://mostwanted.dev:8000/user`. But no username part.

Comment: And what user do you see?

Comment: @ClaudioKing No user at all, `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161` pops up instead.

Comment: Try to change `profile.index` to `usertest` everywhere. And run `php artisan route:clear` before testing.

Comment: Can you post the search view?

Comment: @ClaudioKing Added on

@AlexeyMezenin What do you mean by that? Search and replace everything that has ('profile.index') and replace with ('usertest') then run `php artisan route:clear` ?

Comment: @HongbinWang What request code?

Comment: I mean the search view

Comment: @HongbinWang The Search results view and Controller is there now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify **userblock.blade.php**

```
<div class="media">
<a class="pull-left" href="{{ url('user/'.$user->username) }}">
    <img class="media-object" alt="{{ $user->getNameOrUsername() }}" src="">
</a>
<div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">
        <a href="{{ url('user/'.$user->username) }}">{{ $user->getNameOrUsername() }}</a>
    </h4>
    @if ($user->location)
        <p>{{ $user->location }}</p>
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: Tried changing it to `{{ url('user/'.$user->username) }}` but it still pops `http://mostwanted.dev:8000/user` only (saw that in the Element console).

Comment: check the value and type of $user->username

Comment: Add <p>{{ $user->username }}</p> in your userblock.blade.php and check what it will be

Comment: Nothing is inside the `<p>` at all

Comment: So it is the key of your problem.

Comment: That's really weird because I went into MySQL Workbench and saw that the usernames exist in the database. What am I missing?

Comment: I found out where my problem is. I can't enter a new username because each time I create a new remember token and the username isn't in the same row as the user's account. Is there anyway I can get users to enter their username after they've created an account and have be in the same row as the user account?

Comment: Ah ha, you need update username instead of creating a new user record

Comment: So there's no way I can separate the sign up process and choosing a username? So be it then...

Comment: Yes, you can. sign up create user record with username = null, then update username where user_id = uid

Comment: Update username where user_id = uid?

Comment: $user = $this->getById($id);

$user->username = $request->input('username');

Comment: How can I add validation rules to `'username'` as well?

Comment: This is what I had before:
public function postUsername(Request $request)
    { 
    $this->validate($request, [
    'username' => 'required|unique:users|regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9.]+$/|max:50',
    ]);
   
    User::create([
    'username' => $request->input('username'),
    ]);  
  
    return view('home');

    }

Comment: It is hard to say. Maybe you can post a new question for the validation.

Comment: One last question and I'll open a new question if I must. $id isn't defined in the `$user = $this->getById($id)` How can I define it? $id = ???